# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'django_content_type' in the database

Tags: sql-server, django, django-migrations

I installed Django 3.2.6 and I am able to spin up the server using `python manage.py runserver` however when I want to do migrate through `python manage.py migrate` i am getting the above error message. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by deleting `django_content_type` table and redo migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by first deleting newly created migration file and then running **python manage.py migrate --fake**